# Foreign key of Foreign key in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to create 3 tables and on creating the 3rd table `EMPLOYEE_VALUES` , I am getting an error stating that no matching unique or primary key for this column-list. I have gone through stack overflow posts on the same and tried different ways but could not figure out what is causing this issue. Appreciate if anyone could shed some light on the same

```
CREATE TABLE P_EMPLOYEE_TYPE (
    ID NUMBER(22) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)    
);


CREATE TABLE P_EMPLOYEE(
    P_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID  NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (P_ID) REFERENCES P(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES P_EMPLOYEE_TYPE(ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(P_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
    );

-- The following table is causing the issue 

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_VALUES(
    ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    P_ID NUMBER,
    EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID  NUMBER,
    VALUE VARCHAR2(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID,P_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (P_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES P_EMPLOYEE(P_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
    );
```

Comment: Declare P_ID,EMPLOYEE_TYPR_ID as primary key. Just put PRIMARY KEY after their declaration

Answer (score 1):

You've got it wrong; `employee_values` doesn't fail, but `p_employee does` as it references the `p` table which doesn't exist. This one:

```
SQL> -- This table is missing
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE p
  2  (
  3     id   NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_p PRIMARY KEY
  4  );

Table created.
```

Now, the rest of the tables.

- there's no need to specify `NOT NULL` with primary key constraint columns; they can't be `NULL` anyway
- a good practice says that you should **name** your constraints, otherwise their name is generated by Oracle and is difficult to find among other constraints

So:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE P_EMPLOYEE_TYPE
  2  (
  3     ID     NUMBER (22) CONSTRAINT pk_emptyp PRIMARY KEY,
  4     NAME   VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE P_EMPLOYEE
  2  (
  3     P_ID               NUMBER,
  4     EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID   NUMBER,
  5     --
  6     CONSTRAINT fk_empl_p FOREIGN KEY (P_ID) REFERENCES P (ID),
  7     CONSTRAINT fk_empl_emptyp FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
  8        REFERENCES P_EMPLOYEE_TYPE (ID),
  9     CONSTRAINT pk_empl PRIMARY KEY (P_ID, EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_VALUES
  2  (
  3     ID                 NUMBER (4),
  4     P_ID               NUMBER,
  5     EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID   NUMBER,
  6     VALUE              VARCHAR2 (100),
  7     --
  8     CONSTRAINT pk_empval PRIMARY KEY (ID, P_ID, EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID),
  9     CONSTRAINT fk_empval_emp FOREIGN KEY (P_ID, EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
 10        REFERENCES P_EMPLOYEE (P_ID, EMPLOYEE_TYPE_ID)
 11  );

Table created.
```

Comment: Thank you very much . This really helped . I have had Product table already in there , the problem is, as you specified that there is a not null keyword in my query. I am able to create tables now . Thanks again.